# How to spoof location on android without using Mock Locations?

Tags: android, mocking, manipulate, mock-location

We know that there are various apps like fake my GPS etc. But these apps use the developers options to activate mock locations. The apps that detect mock locations usually check if the permissions  are on or not and they use the below code:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /

I would like to know if there is a way to spoof (change )locations without changing rooting the device or activating mock location setting on Android.

Comment: If you want to test your app, you can also use the emulator and provide a GPS track in the emulator settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use a software-defined radio (SDR) like the HackRF One along with the gps-sdr-sim GitHub project to simulate GPS signals.